# Is it possible to tell a stemmer to ignore words of specific language?

Tags: python, nltk

I am using the Cistem stemmer for the german language.

The documents I am stemming contain also english words.

Therefore I want to tell the german stemmer to ignore the English words and afterwards I want to tell my english stemmer to ignore the german words.

Example:

My German text contains the english word "case".
The German stemmer stems it to "cas", but it should stay "case".
Hence ignoring the english word "case".

Is this possible?

My code:

```
stemmer = Cistem()
sl = []
for line in o: 
    sp = line.split()
    sl.append(sp)

st = [[stemmer.segment(s) for s in l] for l in sl]
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? What is the expected output?

Comment: Hi @mario_sunny, I added an example.

Comment: Did the word frequency method with Spacy work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good approach is to compare the frequency at which a given word appears in a corpus of English documents to the frequency at which that same word appears in a corpus of German documents.
For example if word w1 appears more often in the German wikipedia than it does in the English wikipedia then it is probably a German word.

Now instead of downloading, parsing and calculating word frequencies for these two versions of wikipedia, a more straightforward approach is to use models which have been pre-trained and which include an indication of the word frequencies which they have encountered during training.

We can use an English and a German model in Spacy:

```
import spacy
nlpDE = spacy.load("de_core_news_md")
nlpEN = spacy.load('en_core_web_md')

# some test sentences in both languages:
sl = [ "Python is an interpreted, high-level, general-purpose programming language.",
"Created by Guido van Rossum and first released in 1991, Python's design philosophy emphasizes code readability with its notable use of significant whitespace.", 
"Its language constructs and object-oriented approach aim to help programmers write clear, logical code for small and large-scale projects.", 
"Python ist eine universelle, üblicherweise interpretierte höhere Programmiersprache.",
" Wegen ihrer klaren und übersichtlichen Syntax gilt Python als einfach zu erlernen.",
"Python unterstützt mehrere Programmierparadigmen, z. B. die objektorientierte, die aspektorientierte und die funktionale Programmierung"]

#let's randomly shuffle this list of test sentences:
from random import shuffle
shuffle(sl)
s = " ".join(sl)

#Our function which will compare the likelihoods:
def compare(word):
    prob_en = nlpEN.vocab[word].prob
    prob_de = nlpDE.vocab[word].prob
    if prob_en > prob_de:
        return('EN')
    else:
        return('DE')


doc = nlpEN(s)    
print([(t, compare(t.text))  for t in doc if not t.is_punct])
```

And the result of this method on the sample data:

```
[(Python, 'EN'), (is, 'EN'), (an, 'DE'), (interpreted, 'EN'), (high, 'EN'), (level, 'EN'), 
(general, 'EN'), (purpose, 'EN'), (programming, 'EN'), (language, 'EN'), (Python, 'EN'), 
(unterstützt, 'DE'), (mehrere, 'DE'), (Programmierparadigmen, 'DE'), (z., 'DE'), (B., 'DE'), (die, 'DE'), 
(objektorientierte, 'DE'), (die, 'DE'), (aspektorientierte, 'DE'), (und, 'DE'), (die, 'DE'), (funktionale, 'DE'),
 (Programmierung, 'DE'), (Created, 'EN'), (by, 'EN'), (Guido, 'DE'), (van, 'DE'), (Rossum, 'DE'), (and, 'EN'),
 (first, 'EN'), (released, 'EN'), (in, 'DE'), (1991, 'EN'), (Python, 'EN'), ('s, 'EN'), (design, 'EN'), 
(philosophy, 'EN'), (emphasizes, 'EN'), (code, 'EN'), (readability, 'EN'), (with, 'EN'), (its, 'EN'), 
(notable, 'EN'), (use, 'EN'), (of, 'EN'), (significant, 'EN'), (whitespace, 'EN'), ( , 'EN'), (Wegen, 'DE'), 
(ihrer, 'DE'), (klaren, 'DE'), (und, 'DE'), (übersichtlichen, 'DE'), (Syntax, 'DE'), (gilt, 'DE'), (Python, 'EN'), 
(als, 'DE'), (einfach, 'DE'), (zu, 'DE'), (erlernen, 'DE'), (Python, 'EN'), (ist, 'DE'), (eine, 'DE'), 
(universelle, 'DE'), (üblicherweise, 'DE'), (interpretierte, 'DE'), (höhere, 'DE'), (Programmiersprache, 'DE'),
 (Its, 'EN'), (language, 'EN'), (constructs, 'EN'), (and, 'EN'), (object, 'EN'), (oriented, 'EN'), (approach, 'EN'), 
(aim, 'EN'), (to, 'EN'), (help, 'EN'), (programmers, 'EN'), (write, 'EN'), (clear, 'EN'), (logical, 'EN'),
 (code, 'EN'), (for, 'EN'), (small, 'EN'), (and, 'EN'), (large, 'EN'), (scale, 'EN'), (projects, 'EN')]
```

Comment: Hi @DBaker! I just tried your code (no time these last days) and it worked perfect. Thanks for your detailed answer ! One question: If I want to analyse sentences, can I just change [word] to [sentence] ?

Comment: Hi @gython I am glad that it worked for you! The code analyzes sentences on a word by word basis. That is why each sentence is tokenized into words, then the language of each word is predicted.

Comment: Thanks again @DBaker. Can you recommend me some ressources if I want to do this sentence based and not word based?

Comment: I am not sure exactly what you mean by 'doing it sentence based' : do you mean determining whether a given sentence is in English or German? If that is what you mean then you can count the number of words in that sentence which were predicted  as 'EN' and compare with the number of words that were predicted as 'DE'. I will add a few links to resources in the next comment.

Comment: https://stackabuse.com/python-for-nlp-tokenization-stemming-and-lemmatization-with-spacy-library/ is a good ressource on tokenizing

Answer (score 0):

A straight forward idea would be to check for each token whether it belongs to a given German vocabulary or whether to the English vocab. According to this, you can decide whether to apply the stemmer to the token or not.
For this, you would need a dictionary of the corresponding languages, maybe you could use one from nltk or check against occurence or frequency in a corpus, so that you can assign a probability whether a word is used in the target language or whether it is a borrowing.